# Passing argument of a function to exec in find

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, zsh, rename

I would like to define a function to find and replace text in multiple files. I find the command line

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/<string_to_find>/<string_to_replace>}"' _ {} \;
```

Since I need to use it often I would like to put it into a function inside my `.zshrc` file, something like

```
myrename() {
    find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1/$arg1_myrename/$arg2_myrename}"' _ {} \;
}
```

so that executing as `$ myrename "<string_to_replace>" "<replacement>"` all files in folder having `<string_to_replace>` in the name gets it replaced by `<replacement>`.

Comment: This seems to be what the `rename` utility already does, more or less. You just need to call it for all files that you want to rename.  If you're using `zsh`, you also have `zargs` as a loadable function, that would make calling `find` and `bash` redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the pattern and argument as environment arguments to `find`:

```
myrename(){
    in=$1 out=$2 find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1/$in/$out}"' _ {} \;
}
```

But, as Kusalananda said, this is what `rename` does.

```
myrename(){
    find . -type f -exec rename "s/$1/$2/" {} +
}
```